# Null Object that is a child of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewgroup

I have a `Fragment` that is part of a `ViewPager`. In this `Fragment` I have a `ViewGroup` child. Now, why in my `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` after having instantiated my `ViewPager` and `adapter`, my `Container` is getting `null`?

Here is my `onCreate()`:

```
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewPager mPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mContainerView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
    //Here mContainerView is already null
    ...
}
```

Here is the `Fragment` that is part of a `ViewPager` that contains `mContainerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- This is my ViewGroup -->
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" />

</ScrollView>

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="32dp"
    android:text="@string/message_empty_layout_changes"
    android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you're trying to access the `Fragment`'s `View` (and children) using the `Activity`'s `findViewById()` method. That shouldn't work since the `Fragment` inflates its own layout and `Fragments` are *not* traditional `Views`.

If you know the `Fragment` is instantiated and you can retrieve it, you can get an instance of the `ViewGroup` using

```
yourFragment#getView().findViewById()
```

If not, you can make an interface that your `Activity` implements with a method that accepts a `ViewGroup` as the argument. Then in the Fragment's `onCreateView()`, have the Fragment pass the `ViewGroup` off to the interface. You can cast directly to your `Activity`, but an interface is cleaner.

Eg

```
public class Fragment {

 public interface ViewGroupCreateListener{

     public void onViewGroupCreated (ViewGroup v);
 }

 private ViewGroupCreateListener listener;

 public void onAttach (Activity a){
     super.onAttach (a);
     listener = (ViewGroupCreateListener) a;
 }

public View onCreateView (/*all its arguments here*/){
    View v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.your_layout);
    ViewGroup group = v.findViewById (R.id.container);
    listener.onViewGroupCreated(group);

    return v;
 }
```

}

Your `Activity` would look something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ViewGroupCreateListener, OtherInterface1, OtherInterface2{

  private ViewGroup mViewGroup;


  public void onViewGroupCreated (ViewGroup v){
     mViewGroup = v;
  }
}
```

This is nice since if the pager re-instantiates the `Fragment`, the Activity still gets a valid instance of the `ViewGroup`.

*Or*, if depending on what you're actually trying to achieve with this `ViewGroup`, you may be able to do this processing inside the `Fragment` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't get the instance of the `ViewGroup` with the first option you showed. The app threw me a NPE at the start. Now, the second option sounds good. But, I am already implementing another interface in my main Activity. Here is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/lumalav/6167821); If you don't mind to take a look at. My problem is that I am retrieving a List that the user selects from a Dialog. After that, I want to add a view in the mentioned Fragment, but my `mContainerView` in line 48 of `Fragment1` is null. What can I do to instantiate it in the correct way?

Comment: I tried setting the Interface, but it threw me `08-06 21:48:42.018: E/AndroidRuntime(12352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 21:48:42.018: E/AndroidRuntime(12352): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foodbuilder.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.foodbuilder.Fragment1$ViewGroupCreateListener
`

Comment: @LuisLavieri the stack trace in the gist does not match the code, there is no `line 67`.
Regarding everything else: 
1) There is no limit to the number of interfaces that can be implemented by a class.
2) For the Dialog logic, if the Fragment should not launch the Dialog, would then do it as such: Dialog updates, passes data to the Activity, Activity updates Fragment (almost like you have now). If your implement the interface in my answer, it should work as expected and you avoid the `static` variables.

Comment: You still need to implement the interface in `MainActivity`. Multiple interfaces can be implemented, just separate with commas (see edit in post)

Comment: Alright, let me try again. line 67 is `.addView()`. I didn't paste the complete code in gist; just what I thought was important. I don't know where I read that you couldn't add more than one interface in Java.

Comment: It threw me the same Exception. `08-06 22:05:03.926: E/AndroidRuntime(14533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 22:05:03.926: E/AndroidRuntime(14533): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foodbuilder.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.foodbuilder.Fragment1$ViewGroupCreateListener
08-06 22:05:03.926: E/AndroidRuntime(14533):  at com.foodbuilder.Fragment1.onAttach(Fragment1.java:40)
`

Comment: @LuisLavieri Are you sure that `com.foodbuilder.MainActivity` `implements` `Fragment1.ViewGroupCreateListener` like I outlined in my answer? Maybe add another gist, something is definitely missing. Also try cleaning and rerunning the project.

Comment: Yeah. I tried it, but it worked! I didn't pass `group` to the MainActivity, and I just used it from the Fragment; I avoided implementing the interface, but worked. Thank you very much for your help buddy. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: No problem, I guess your solution falls under the *"Or, you may be able to do this processing inside the Fragment itself."* part of my answer. I am curious, what did you do instead? Keep You are allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: Correct! I just instantiated the `ViewGroup group` after the `View` as you suggested in your answer, and use it in my `update()` that you saw in my gist. Now, going back to the question of my post, my problem was that I couldn't understand that I had to `inflate` my `View` before instantiating the `ViewGroup`. You helped me with that. Thanks again.